# Are abstract type members a compile time construct?

Tags: scala, abstract-type

Scala: Are abstract type members a compile time construct?

Are they erased like type parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both abstract and concrete type members are a compile time construct. They disappear after `scalac`'s erasure step, as can be seen with `scalac -Xprint:erasure`.